# How come Instagram requires me to log in to view an image when using IE, but not Firefox?

Tags: instagram

When I attempt to open a link to an Instagram pic or an Instagram profile while using IE, it forces me to a generic landing page where I have to login before I can proceed.  When I open that same link with Firefox, I am taken straight to the pic or profile.  Why is that?

Comment: Firefox is remembering your login information? IE is treating cookies differently?

Comment: @Krampus Perhaps I should have mentioned that I've never logged into Instagram.  I don't even have an Instagram account.  I experience the same behavior on both my work and home PC.